# WWD2017 pdfkit to fill PDF form

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, pdfkit

In my swift application there is PDF form field which with all the fields name defined, I want to fill  these fields programmatically, however watching the WWDC presentation, [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit) first draw a frame around the field, meaning creating form field first than setting the vale as

textField.widgetStringVale = “WWDC 2017”

My questions are

1) is it possible to fill the PDF form with fields already created in adobe acrobat in swift programmatically instead of creating first using PDFKit

2) if not for 1) how to determine the absolute frame size for fields as there are many field so I don’t want to trial and error

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use PDFKit to programmatically fill a PDF form:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

let pdfURL = ...
let document = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL!)
let page1 = document!.page(at: 0)

let field = page1?.annotations.filter({ $0.fieldName! == "ConferenceName" })
field?[0].widgetStringValue = "WWDC 2017"

let saveURL = ...
document!.write(to: saveURL)
```

Comment: How would you loop through an array of fieldNames to update several field values?

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a save function that works for testing purposes too

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

 let pdfURL = ...
 let document = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL!)
 let page1 = document!.page(at: 0)

 let field = page1?.annotations.filter({ $0.fieldName! == "ConferenceName" })
 field?[0].widgetStringValue = "WWDC 2017"

 savePDF()
}

 func savePDF() {
    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    let path = URL(string: "file:///Users/bbird/Desktop/PDFKit/awesome.pdf")!
    #else
    let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!.appendingPathComponent("awesome.pdf")
    #endif
    print(path)
    self.pdfView?.document?.write(to: path) //We don't really need to write this here - just demo'ing code
   }
```